# Can't Start Redmine After Installing Plugin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, redmine

I just installed this plugin for my redmine: https://github.com/masweetman/issue_charts

After that, I can't go to my redmine webpage, here is the error log:

```
4mipkJBT
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, here is the link to pastebin: https://pastebin.com/4mipkJBT

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: Yes, I did. No errors at all.

Comment: Have you looked in log/production.log or development.log?